# How to get all combination, cell (row*column mapping) wise in a pandas data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python pandas data-frame like

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

All I need is

```
A B C
1 2 3
1 2 6
1 5 3
1 5 6
4 2 3
4 2 6
4 5 3
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with each column, then [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html)

```
res = (
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[col] for col in df], 
                               names=df.columns)
      .to_frame(index=False)
)
print(res)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  6
2  1  5  3
3  1  5  6
4  4  2  3
5  4  2  6
6  4  5  3
7  4  5  6
```

Edit: if you have `list` or `dict` in cells, maybe consider to use [`itertool.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product

res = pd.DataFrame(
    list(product(*[df[col] for col in df])),
    columns=df.columns
)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Ben.T, will this works if we have different data types in cell like list dict etc.